# Watson Speech To Text API returns empty response

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, guzzle, speech-to-text

I am trying to get a transcript for recorded audio trough microphone using Watson Text To Speech API. Using Vue in frontend, PHP in backend and Guzzle to make the request.

Recording the audio starts when user clicks on button and also ends on button click, that's when I send the data to backend and make the request to API. The problem is that I am getting an empty response. There are no errors or anything.

This is how far I've gotten: in fronted I use MediaRecorder for recording the audio, when audio recording stops I make a blob from the data recorded with corresponding mimetype and convert it to base64 string and send it to backend, like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
.then(stream => {
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    this.mediaRecorder.start();

    let audioChunks = [];
    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        const mimeType = this.mediaRecorder.mimeType;
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {type: mimeType});

        const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        stream.removeTrack(audioTrack);

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(audioBlob);

        reader.onload = () => {
            const recording = reader.result;

            this.makeRequest(url, 'POST', {'audio': recording, 'mimeType': mimeType})
                .then(response => {
                    // filter response
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    //
                });

            this.mediaRecorder = null;
        };
    });
})
```

In back-end I decode the base64 string and save it to file, then I send it to Speech To Text API, like this:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent());
$formatted_str = str_replace("data:{$data->mimeType};base64,", "", $data->audio);
$recording = base64_decode($formatted_str);

$filename = Uuid::uuid4()->toString() . ".webm";
file_put_contents($filename, $recording);

$client = new GuzzleClient([
   'base_uri' => $baseUrl
]);

try {
    $apiRequest = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', $clientUrl);
    $apiRequestParams = [
        'auth' => ['apikey', $apiKey],
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => $data->mimeType
        ],
          'model' => 'en-GB_BroadbandModel',
          'body' => file_get_contents($filename)
    ];

    $response = $client->send($apiRequest, $apiRequestParams);

    $data = $response;

   return new JsonModel([
       'data' => $data
   ]);
```

All I get is response with an empty body. Request status code is 200.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` is for creating a filehandle and will not read any data. You will probably want `file_get_contents`

Comment: I tried that too, the result is the same - empty response. Edited original code.